# store json value as session in angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have a php file which returns json result based from a $http post as seen here:

[json result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prqrS.png)

now, in my controller below, i want to store `03-1314-00916` or  `data[0]['student_number']` as a session in angular so i can use it anywhere in any of my controllers. How will i make it.

```js
app.controller('signInCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
  $scope.txtUsername = '';
  $scope.txtPassword = '';

  $scope.signIn = function(){
    $http.post('http://infoyon_login.php',
      {'username' : this.txtUsername, 'password': this.txtPassword})
    .success(function(data){
      if(data[0]['logged'] === true)
      {
        $scope.unable = false;
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[0]['student_number']);
  here --> someSessionVar = data[0]['student_number'];      
        //window.location = '#/app/dashboard';
      }else{
        //console.log('unable to login');
        $scope.unable = true;

      }
      //console.log(data[0]['logged']);
    })
  }
}) //end controller
```

Comment: Use sessionStorage(). from HTML5

setItem('key', value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML5 sessionStorage

```
if(data[0]['logged'] === true)
  {
    $scope.unable = false;
    console.log(data[0]);
    console.log(data[0]['student_number']);
    sessionStorage.setItem('student_number', data[0]['student_number']);      
    //window.location = '#/app/dashboard';
  }
```

To retrieve

```
   $scope.studentNumber = sessionStorage.getItem('student_number');
```

Comment: Thanks! Life Saver!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a service. If you need it to be present before the page is resolved, you'll want to call that service from within a `$route.resolve()` function, which you will add to your `$routeProvider` logic. As for the method, you can use the web storage API as described in the first answer, or if it is a critical part of the application you might consider storing it in `$rootScope`. Caveat: other commenters may disagree with that option, but there is indeed a time and a place to use `$rootScope`.